# How much natural gas does France import from Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, trade, france, gas

[According to the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61073894)

> France, like many other European countries, imports much of its natural gas through pipelines from Russia, using it for residential and commercial energy.

Of course, "much" is not exactly quantified, so how much is "much"?

Answer (score 8):

France imports 16.8% of its natural gas from Russia ([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf8KM.jpg) via @Fizz which in turn relies upon Eurostat).

These imports account for [about 3.7% of Russia's natural gas exports](https://www.iea.org/articles/energy-fact-sheet-why-does-russian-oil-and-gas-matter), which can be compared to the roughly [74% of all Russian natural gas exports](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=51618) that are imported by OECD European nations.

France also uses [significantly less natural gas per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_natural_gas_consumption) than many other European nations because it does not rely upon natural gas to generate electricity to a meaningful extent, while many European countries are heavily dependent upon natural gas fueled electricity generation. But, because France is a fairly high population industrialized country, its natural gas demand is still not insignificant.

Comment: So it's not very important for France and France could probably do without Russian gas quite easily if it wanted to? Just save a bit and order a few million million cubic meters more from somewhere else.

Comment: @Trilarion Those questions are much harder to answer and I don't know the answer to them. There are few good substitute fuels for dedicated natural gas equipment and obtaining supplies from elsewhere is non-trivial. A Jimmy Carter style "sweater" campaign this winter might be in order in France, however.

Comment: Also, many buildings in France use electricity for heating (e.g. heat pump) instead of gas.

Comment: @Trilarion: 1) Nearly 1/5th of supply is not "save a bit". The US uses 15% of its natural gas in "residential uses" (like heating homes and cooking, and since the US uses 38% of Natural Gas for electricity generation, France's residential usage is likely higher). Asking people to cook 1/5th less and heat their houses 1/5th less is a hard sell (especially if Omicron forces another lockdown)  2) If everyone/many people avoid Russian natural gas, the price for non-Russian natural gas will go up immensely.

Comment: @sharur A combination of using less, using substitutes and buying somewhere else to save 20% should at the very least be possible for a rich country like France. On the other hand it would be more expensive. Price is also a good driver to lower consumption. As long as politicians can lower the impact on lower incomes.

Comment: France hardly uses gas for electricity generation, on the other hand, homes frequently uses gas for cooking, which is rare/outdated elsewhere as far as I know. Also, France has a significant amout of domestic-produced gas through methanisation.

Comment: @sharur Substituting electricity for natural gas in cooking, at least as a temporary stopgap measure in a crisis like this one is easy. Substituting electricity for natural gas in space heating and water heating is possible (as is reducing demand through better insulation), but a much more difficult thing to do in the short run. In the short run, however, reducing space heating natural gas consumption means keeping indoor temperatures in the colder months lower. Ramping up production is an intermediate time horizon between retrofitting homes and businesses and short run measures.

Answer (score 5):

You can play around Eurostat's ['Imports of natural gas by partner country'](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/NRG_TI_GAS/) dataset for this info - the latest figures for French imports are from 2020, although there's a rather large amount for which the source isn't specified:

| Source | Natural Gas Imports (in millions of cubic metres) |
| --- | --- |
| Norway | 16,652.066 |
| Not specified | 7,935.255 |
| Russia | 7,780.367 |
| Netherlands | 3,861.433 |
| Algeria | 3,623.014 |
| Nigeria | 3,421.473 |
| United States | 1,123.814 |
| Qatar | 694.215 |
| Belgium | 637.192 |
| Spain | 383.117 |
| Germany | 209.183 |

Or, in graphical form (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: Also somewhat useful from that dataset: imports from Russia vs total imports by country https://imgur.com/a/dQMpFHa

Comment: Does the dataset also specify a total?

Comment: The only issue I have with this answer is that it doesn't answer the question directly (as it exists now). The OP specifically asks about France and maybe the links specify that, but none of the current graphs or tables mention France specifically. Not worth a downvote from me tho, btw.

Comment: @coblr the graph and table both refer to French imports.

Comment: the not specified and the non gas producing countries (like Belgium) might make the amount of gas that has a Russian origin bigger.

Comment: @CDJB, sorry, you're correct. I did not see the header, only looked at the names at the bottom and thought it was global exports from Russia and not imports from France. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

- On the one hand, natural gas plays a relatively minor role in the French energy mix, since France heavily relies on nuclear energy, which furnishes most of its needs in electricity and to significant extent in heating.
- On the other hand, France is a heavily industrialized country, which needs natural gas for its industry (metallurgy, ceramic production, etc.) In addition, some public facilities traditionally rely on natural gas (and other hydrocarbons) for heating and cooking, although these are also being largely replaced by electricity-based devices.

An approximate breakdown of the electricity production by EDF, the principal electric company in France is:

- nuclear: 74.5%
- hydro-electric: 16.3%
- thermal: 9.1%
- wind power and other renewable sources: 0.1%

For overall energy consumption see [Energy in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_in_France)
[image]

For French energy consumption in comparison to other countries see the [List of countries by natural gas consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_natural_gas_consumption) (France is #20)

See also the [List of countries by natural gas production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_natural_gas_production), where France is 89th.

Comment: Ok, so how much they import form Russia?

Comment: @Fizz You mean the fraction of what they consume? By fraction of their total energy consumption? The fraction of the total Russian exports to Europe? The fraction of total Russian exports? There is plenty of material to be found by googling - take no offense, but this question is poorly researched.

Comment: Informative but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @ohwilleke see my comment above. If one wants to apply rigorously the forum rules, one has to do it consistently: poorly researched question is -1; unclear question is a reason for closure.

Comment: This answer is needed as a reference. If France imported just 1m³ of methane per year, directly from Russia, it would "import 100% of its methane from Russia". It doesn't mean that France would be very dependent on Russia, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil *Of course, "much" is not exactly quantified, so how much is "much"?* In my opinion *how much* here can be interpreted in many different ways. I gave a few, and in a comment above pointed a few others, which require just some googling.

Comment: @RogerVadim When you consider a question unclear, then you should vote to close and request clarification before you attempt to answer it. But I don't really see what's unclear about this question.

Comment: @Philipp I explained above (at least twice) what is unclear about it. I also pointed out that it is poorly research, as a brief google search shows. However, I don't see you or anyone who chipped in above downvoting or commenting about it. So, thank you for your unsolicited opinion, but I judge you by your actions.

Comment: @RogerVadim I think the question is pretty clear. Even if you don't read the body of the question, the title says: "How much natural gas does France import from Russia?" I don't see the answer in your writing.

Comment: I don't see a line anywhere that says: "France imports X cubic meters of gas per year from Russia"

Comment: @MithridatestheGreat So, is it "How much of its total gas imports France imports from Russia?", "How much gas France imports compared to other countries?", "How much natural gas France imports in respect to its total energy consumption?" etc. Either you and other people who commented above are unable to see the range of options... or the motivation for these comments is something else than enforcing forum rules. The fact that none of you obviously has a problem with the part *The question does not show any research effort" is rather telling.

Comment: @SurpriseDog see the comment above. Note that I have already stated all these points in the comments above, so I won't go on debating: the beauty of online discussions is that anyone can read them and make their own judgement about how solid each sides arguments.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm beginning to think that you are talking in a language other than English... It's interesting that you **insist** that you are answering the question correctly, which is obviously wrong. So, if that really matters, why you didn't ask for clarity from OP to see if he/she is looking for total, fraction, compared to other countries, etc.? If you really think without explicit definition from OP answering this question is pointless, so why you even bothered to write this thing up?

Comment: @MithridatestheGreat I talk in several languages other than English. But even in English there possible multiple interprétations of this question, as I demonstrated above. That you ignored all that, as well as the other problematic points with the question and with several people over focusing on this answer has to do with something else than native language: intelligence, imagination, logical rigour, cognitive biases, etc.